# Unlock door with no knob

Tags: doors, lock, interior

Any suggestions for how to unlock and open a door with this type of lock? A video on YouTube showed me how to remove the knobs since the push button lock would not release. I have tried using scissors to turn the latch, as well as a hanger to see if it could be jimmied, and small screwdrivers to see if the lock itself could be released. No luck. It does not pull left toward the hinges and only pushes a half centimeter toward the door jam.
[image: exposed lock]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless your house is abnormally well built, a prybar applied at the strike plate will find enough flex in the frame to pop the door open. Otherwise see @mikes answer.

Answer (score 30):

I would remove the hinge pins and unmount the door. Once removed, the hardware should be visible to remove the bolt assembly.

Comment: That works 50% of the time. The other 50% has the hinges on the other side of the door

Comment: ...but given the direction of the strike plate, they are on this side, this time.

Comment: Removing the door hinges worked. Problem solved! Thank you!!

Comment: ...then you ( @Janie ) should "accept" this answer, not mine. (The green checkmark, and yes, you can change it.) Lord knows I don't need the points, and this was the one that actually worked for you.

Comment: @Janie Great work!  What was the root cause ?  was the mechanism stuck ?

Comment: @Janie you should change the accepted answer

Answer (score 5):

Sliding a cake knife, piece of plastic (credit card or similar) down at a 45 or 60 degree angle in the gap where the strike plate is, start above, while pushing gently on the door is usually enough to slide the plunger back and allow the door to open.

Comment: I suspect the mechanism completely rusted and seized up. Otherwise this would work.

Comment: @Nelson It's always worth a shot, especially after a round or two of WD40. I've seen rusted parts move that I never thought I'd see moving again after that.

Comment: In this case, the slanted side of the plunger is pointed away from us, but you can still get around that using a piece of stiff wire (the handle from a typical Chinese takeout container works very well for this) and looping around the plunger while pulling both the wire and door towards you.  I've done the same trick with a piece of string or ribbon, but wire is much easier since you can make a stiff loop with it.

Answer (score 4):

This looks like the sort of latch which is activated by pressing the end of the piston-like piece *towards* the strike plate.  If it's not sticking this can be done with your fingers, otherwise MacGyver some sort of prying scheme.